# replicate jQuery touch even binding

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove dependency on jQuery from a project. Currently I have something like this...

```
$("#input").ontouchstart = myFunction;
```

Now I want to use vanilla js like this

```
somehowBind('touchstart', document.getElementById('input'), myFunction)
```

I don't mind the syntax, just want the same functionality.

Comment: _"I am trying to remove dependency on jQuery from a project."_ **WHY?**

Comment: Using webview embedded in keyboard replacement app for android. I am experiencing some performance issues. I want to strip the code down, make it simpler, as keboard app should have as low overhead as possible so as not to interfere with main apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, should be:

```
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('touchstart', myFunction)
```

Although I've never heard of the "touchstart" event. Is it Mobile only?

Comment: Yeah - is mobile only. I will try this. Thanks